# Django pre_save signals work when Model is saved but not ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I created a pre_save signal to check if a field was updated before savings a model and shoot off a webhook if so. This works fine when I edit the model from ./manage.py shell and save it, but if I edit it on my site, which utilizes a form, it does not fire off the webhook. Why is this?

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ClientConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'client'
    verbose_name = "Clients"
    label = 'client'

    def ready(self):
        import client.signals
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ClientContact)
def send_hook_on_roadmap_update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Watches for ClientContacts to be saved and checks to see if the
    pipeline attribute has changed.
    """
    try:
        obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        pass  # Object is new, so field hasn't technically changed
    else:
        if not obj.pipeline == instance.pipeline:  # Field has changed
            instance.pipeline_updated()
```

models.py

```
class ClientContact(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=30, )
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=30, )
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), blank=True, max_length=75)
    create_date = models.DateField(_("Creation date"))
    address = models.ForeignKey('AddressBook', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    pipeline = models.ForeignKey(Pipeline, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

forms.py

```
class ContactModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, client, organization, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'title',
            'email',
            'address',
            'pipeline',
        )
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.html5_required = True
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('contact_save', 'Save'))
        self.fields['address'].queryset = AddressBook.objects.filter(organization=client)
        self.fields['pipeline'].queryset = Pipeline.objects.filter(organization=organization)

    class Meta:
        model = ClientContact
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'title', 'email', 'address', 'pipeline')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it does not work, but I would suggest you to move that function to your models save method.

```
class ClientContact(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=30, )
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=30, )
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), blank=True, max_length=75)
    create_date = models.DateField(_("Creation date"))
    address = models.ForeignKey('AddressBook', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    pipeline = models.ForeignKey(Pipeline, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #check if obj is new or being updated
        try:
            obj = ClientContact.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if not obj.pipeline == self.pipeline:  # Field has changed
                self.pipeline_updated()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        #call super and store data
        super(ClientContact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Dunno what the initial problem was, but this fixed me up. Thanks!